# Rails : Show records by months in the view, any other way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sqlite, enumeration

**SCENARIO:**
I have bunch of matches. I want to create in my view a side column with HTML links where you can view the matches by month. Here is my current implementation:

**CURRENT SOLUTION**:

```
#Controller
@matches_by_month = Match.find(:all).group_by {|match| match.kickoff.strftime('%B %Y')}

#View
<%  @matches_by_month.each do | month, matches | %>
<%=link_to month %><br>
<% end %>

# Returns in the side column links that look like this.
# April 2011
# May 2011
# Which is great!
```

**SEEKING ADVICE:**
I'm thinking that this is not a good solution because over a period of time this page will slow down. Right? By 2013 I could have 1500 records and **it seems like a waste to continuously find(:all) matches in order to get the months.** Is there another solution I can use? Should I keep a separate table outside of 'matches' that tracks the months. Maybe I'm overhtinking this and the current solution is ok. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is safe to assume that there are matches every month between the first record and the last record you can:

```
# for your sidebar
start_date = Match.first.kickoff.to_date
end_date = Match.last.kickoff.to_date

<% start_date.step(end_date, 1.month) do |date| %>
  <%= link_to date.strftime('%%B %Y'), matches_by_month_path(date) %>
<% end %>
```

And then in your controller just parse the date selected and do a conditional find using `Match.where(...)`.

Comment: For some reason the 'step method is generating an error. I trie your solution out and I get the following error. "undefined method `step' for 2011-04-02 12:45:00 UTC:Time"

Comment: `Time` doesn't have a `step` method. Just convert them to dates. I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: That fixed it and this solution is great as long as I have matches every month. BUT if I don't have matches every month (i.e. offseason) is it safe to say my first solution is what I would need to use?

Comment: @neuone Perhaps, yes. If you utilize memcache to cache the DB result then even with 1500+ rows you should be okay. You might instead want to use SQL functions to grab the months from the posts, too. It's much faster, especially if you have those columns indexed.

Comment: I'll take a look at memcache and how an SQLite3 statement could look like. Thanks for the insight.